# CURL (PHP) - Operation timed out regardless of successful call

Tags: php, api, curl, bigcommerce, php-curl

I'm facing quite weird issue related to CURL (triggered from PHP level) and BigCommerce API.

For weeks my calls were working without any issues, but since couple of days I'm experiencing "Operation timed out after 60001 milliseconds with 0 bytes received" error.

The weird part it that API operation on BigCommerce end is successful - it's a product creation call and product is created successfully.

In CURLOPT_VERBOSE info I can see that the call is failing right after "We are completely uploaded and fine", which is suggesting me that the issue is somewhere on my side and not on the remote platform which is handling API calls.

Here's my PHP code which is triggering CURL call:

```
$this->addHeader('Content-Type', $this->getContentType());
$this->addHeader('Connection', 'close');

if (!is_string($body)) {
 $body = json_encode($body);
}

$this->initializeRequest();

curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_PUT, false);
curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, false);
curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);
curl_exec($this->curl);

return $this->handleResponse();
```

Here is the CURLOPT_VERBOSE dump:

```
* Hostname api.bigcommerce.com was found in DNS cache
*   Trying 34.96.84.189...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to api.bigcommerce.com (34.96.84.189) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=US; ST=Texas; L=Austin; O=BigCommerce, Inc.; CN=*.bigcommerce.com
*  start date: Mar 16 00:00:00 2022 GMT
*  expire date: Mar  7 23:59:59 2023 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "api.bigcommerce.com" matched cert's "*.bigcommerce.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; CN=DigiCert TLS RSA SHA256 2020 CA1
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> POST /stores/[sensitive-data-trimmed-out]/v3/catalog/products HTTP/1.1
Host: api.bigcommerce.com
Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip, br
X-Auth-Client: [sensitive-data-trimmed-out]
X-Auth-Token: [sensitive-data-trimmed-out]
Content-Type: application/json
Connection: close
Accept: application/json
Content-Length: 4009
Expect: 100-continue

< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
* We are completely uploaded and fine
* Operation timed out after 60001 milliseconds with 0 bytes received
* Closing connection 0
[2022-09-08 05:29:33] [ERROR] Message: M\BcBundle\VendorExtends\Bigcommerce\Api\NetworkError: Operation timed out after 60001 milliseconds with 0 bytes received (uncaught exception) at Connection.php line 280 while running console command `m:bc:export:process`
File: ConsoleExceptionListener.php 
Line: 37 
Class: M\PaymentsBundle\EventListener\ConsoleExceptionListener 
Function: onConsoleException[2022-09-08 05:29:33] [ERROR] Message: Error thrown while running command "m:bc:export:process 163 1301 1950". Message: "Operation timed out after 60001 milliseconds with 0 bytes received"
File: ErrorListener.php 
Line: 48 
Class: Symfony\Component\Console\EventListener\ErrorListener 
Function: onConsoleError
In Connection.php line 280:

Operation timed out after 60001 milliseconds with 0 bytes received
```

Any hints are more than welcome.

Comment: So your command `m:bc:export:process 163 1301 1950` takes too long. Debug that and not cUrl request

Comment: @Justinas I don't think that this is the issue because the error is raised by CURL. It's not a "Maximum execution time" error thrown by PHP itself.

Comment: Maybe because there is no max execution time limit for CLI scripts?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I resolved the issue. It was strictly related to product images and BC PHP API library flaw.

In my product creation API calls, I'm using image links, which are leading to my server. The server is also running the app which is performing those API calls.

My application is using BigCommerce PHP API library. I noticed, that when exporting thousands of products, number of used ports on the server is shooting up to values like 10 000 or even 30 000.

It turned out that the BC PHP library is **not closing curl connections** properly. My exports were timed out because BC was not able to download images, because **all ports on the server were busy**!

In order to resolve the issue, in the BC PHP API library I added `curl_close($this->curl)` just before the `return` statement in `handleResponse` method in `Connection` class.

```
private function handleResponse()
{
    if (curl_errno($this->curl)) {
        throw new NetworkError(curl_error($this->curl), curl_errno($this->curl));
    }

    $body = ($this->rawResponse) ? $this->getBody() : json_decode($this->getBody());
    
    $status = $this->getStatus();

    if ($status >= 400 && $status <= 499) {
        if ($this->failOnError) {
            throw new ClientError($body, $status);
        } else {
            $this->lastError = $body;
            curl_close($this->curl);
            return false;
        }
    } elseif ($status >= 500 && $status <= 599) {
        if ($this->failOnError) {
            throw new ServerError($body, $status);
        } else {
            $this->lastError = $body;
            curl_close($this->curl);
            return false;
        }
    }

    if ($this->followLocation) {
        $this->followRedirectPath();
    }

    curl_close($this->curl); /* Close connection */
    return $body;
}
```

Also, I needed to implement slight destructor modification in order to prevent errors which may happen when the script will try to close already closed connection.

```
public function __destruct()
{
    try {
        if (is_resource($this->curl)) { /* Prevent closing closed connetions. */
            curl_close($this->curl);
        }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

After those modifications, port usage on the server went back to normal, BC is able to download images and the timeout issue is gone.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try with set timeout in curl and php.

To tell Curl to never timeout when a transfer is still active, you need to set CURLOPT_TIMEOUT to 0.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0);
```

In PHP, again, you must remove time limits or PHP it self (after 30 seconds by default) will kill the script along Curl's request. This alone should fix your issue.
In addition, if you require data integrity, you could add a layer of security by using ignore_user_abort:

## The maximum execution time, in seconds. If set to zero, no time limit is imposed.

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

## Make sure to keep alive the script when a client disconnect.

```
ignore_user_abort(true);
```

A client disconnection will interrupt the execution of the script and possibly damaging data,
eg. non-transitional database query, building a config file, ecc., while in your case it would download a partial file... and you might, or not, care about this.